# What is the most efficient circuit to control a 3-phase controlled rectifier circuit with the ability to control the firing angle?

Tags: rectifier, thyristor, scr, full-bridge

I am trying to design a board to control a 3-phase full wave rectifier with the ability to control the firing angle (alpha) through a potentiometer or a selector, and I was wondering what are the most recent designs or IC's that are available that I can make use of.

Comment: what do you mean by `firing angle`? ... are you talking about a phase shift between the input and the output

Comment: It is the angle at which the SCR gets turned on and starts conducting.. when to apply the gate pulse to control SCR/Thyristor

Comment: why are SCRs in a full wave rectifier circuit?

Comment: It's a Three phase full wave controlled rectifier...
[link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Three+phase+full+wave+controlled+rectifier&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtktq36s37AhXODewKHbvdC2MQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=969&dpr=1)